# getting ImportError: cannot import name 'HAProxyServer'

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.6

from haproxystats import HAProxyServer

class HAProxyServer:
    haproxy=HAProxyServer('x.x.x.x:x222')
    for b in haproxy.backends:
        print('%s: %s' % (b.name, b.status))
```

if i run the above code i am getting error

python3.6 hatop.py

````
  File "hatop.py", line 3, in <module>
    from haproxystats import HAProxyServer
ImportError: cannot import name 'HAProxyServer'```
````

Answer (score 1):

This means that, the module "HAProxyServer" is not present in your python module.
You will have to install it using the below command:

```
pip install haproxy-stats
```

Please refer the official documentation:

https://github.com/bcicen/haproxy-stats

Comment: ERROR:haproxystats:Error fetching stats from http://x.x.x.x:5222/;csv;norefresh:
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine("<?xml version='1.0'?><stream:stream xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams' id='2954829834' from='xxxxx' version='1.0' xml:lang=''><stream:error><xml-not-well-formed xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'></xml-not-well-formed></stream:error></stream:stream>",))

Comment: i am using the code from https://github.com/bcicen/haproxy-stats